# Windows. setting autorefresh on firefox with vim, mozrepl and putty

Tags: windows, firefox, vim, putty, mozrepl

Anybody knows how? I followed [this detailed tutorial](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Automatically_refresh_display_of_html_on_saving_file) but seems to work only in linux.

Then I tried nearly everything:

- Edit: I managed an improvement by using Putty raw and changing !echo -linux- with !start -win- . but currently I only manage to open form within vim a working Putty console connected with mozrepl.

  silent !start Putty -raw localhost 4242 -m c:\my_commands.txt

So the above works, but the BrowseReload() and the other commands, supossed to work in Putty with a -m and stored in a file, fail silently.

- It seems Putty refuses to log anything, even selecting it on config, so I have no idea why it fails.
- I also tried Plink out of desperation, but to no avail.

Any help is most welcome.

Note that there's an answered question 'Programming Firefox with MozRepl in windows' wich I read. That I have covered, what I need is the Vim connection.

Comment: Why don't you simply use an extension like [Auto Reload](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/auto-reload/)?

Comment: It sems that i'd have to explicitly mark the files to reload. And i'm editing a prestashop site with a lot of css files. With vim + mozrepl i'd have that covered automatically. Also, the fun factor. I'd love to fiddle with firefox from within vim.